# On the binomial series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Let $\alpha$ be an integer greater than $1$. The binomial series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{1/\alpha}{n}x^n$$ converges whenever $\lvert x\rvert<1$, and if $f(x)$ is its sum, we have that $$f(x)^\alpha=1+x,$$ so that $f(x)$ is one of the $\alpha$th roots of $1+x$. If $0<x<1$ then the terms of the series, from $2$nd one onwards, alternate in sign and decrease in absolute value, so that the usual bounds that come out of Leibneiz's criterion imply that $f(x)$ is a positive number, and this determines which $\alpha$th root it is.

When $-1<x<0$ all terms after the $0$th one are negative.

> Can anyone think of a simple argument to prove that the sum of the series is still positive?

I need this in a context where I only have available knowledge about sequences and series of numbers — not even continuity or derivatives yet!

Comment: Do you have IVT? You can argue from continuity of $f(x)$.  If there is some $x \in (-1, 1)$ with $f(x) \leq 0$, then at some $x$ strictly between $-1$ and $1$ we have $f(x) = 0$, but then $f(x)^\alpha = 0 \neq 1+x$. edit: nevermind, I see you don't have continuity...

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to notice that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{1/\alpha}{n}x^n$ is equal to the square, computed à la Cauchy, of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{1/2\alpha}{n}x^n$, so it is positive.
This follows immediately from the Chu–Vandermonde identity.